# Angular 2.1.0 Parent component does not caught event emitted from a child component

Tags: angular

This is the common pattern where there is a List and a Form to creating new items. The form is displayed on a bootstrap modal and it use a service for sending the item to the backend. The service responds with the item if was OK or an error message. The idea is notify the List component with the item for being added to it. Form emits an event with the new item, but parent method never is called.

**List**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-list',
  template: `<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" (click)="createItem()">Create Item</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Static modal -->
<app-item-form></app-item-form>

<div class="row" (itemSaved)="addItem($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items>
    <div class="col-md-4 card-box">
      <app-item [item]="item"></app-item>
  </div>
</div>`
})
export class ItemListComponent {
  items: Item[];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private itemService: ItemService) {
  }

  @ViewChild(ItemFormComponent) private itemFormComponent;
  createItem() {
    this.itemFormComponent.open();
  }

  // This should be called!
  addItem(event:any) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.item != undefined) {
      this.items.push(event.item);
    }
  }

}
```

**Form**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-form',
  template: `<div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="childModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{ modalTitle }}</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form *ngIf="item" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
              <input [(ngModel)]="item.title" type="text" placeholder="Item title" name="title" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
          </div>
 </form>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="childModal.hide()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save(); childModal.hide()">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`
})
export class ItemFormComponent {
  item: Item = new Item();
  @Output() itemSaved = new EventEmitter<Item>();
  modalTitle = 'New Item';

  constructor(
    private itemService: ItemService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  save() {
    this.ItemService
        .save(this.item)
        .then(it => {
          this.item = new Item();
          this.itemSaved.emit(it);
        })
        .catch(error => {}); 
  }

  @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal:ModalDirective;
  open() {
    this.childModal.show();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent component (ItemListComponent) needs to bind an event handler that responds to the child event payload ($event).

You added the event handler to the div with the "row" class. Try this instead:

```
<!-- Static modal -->
<app-item-form (itemSaved)="addItem($event)"></app-item-form>
```

You can read more about parent-child communication via events in the official documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent.

Answer (score 3):

**Correct place**:

```
<app-item-form (itemSaved)="addItem($event)">   //<<---put it here
</app-item-form>
```

**wrong place**:

```
<div class="row" (itemSaved)="addItem($event)">  //<<---not needed here
```